# Sitecore dynamic data sources

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, datasource, sitecore7

I've been working on some components for my website using Sitecore MVC. The data source items for all these components reside in this fashion, under the page item in a components folder.

- sitecore

  - content

    - website

      - home
      - page1
      - components

        - datasourceitem1
        - datasourceitem2
        - datasourceitem3

I've been using "./components" to give the user option to create or select data source items for components. Here is a screenshot

[image]

These components can be reused on different pages and some data source items may reside in an area other than the Components folder. For this reason, I would like to vary this Data Source field to point to different areas of my content tree.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Sitecore 7.0 with MVC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate different datasource locations using pipe |

like this

```
./Components|/sitecore/content/Site/Site Components/Whatever
```

I mean the field `Datasource Location` of the component sublayout

Comment: of course the pipe .. i'll give that a try tomorrow and let you know how that went